# How can I prove by mathematical induction that $\sum_{i=0}^n i^4 = (\sum_{i=0}^n i)^3$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, induction

How can I prove by mathematical induction that $$\sum_{i=0}^n i^4 = (\sum_{i=0}^n i)^3$$ ?

I see easily that it holds for $i=0$.

Using the inductive hypothesis, I get: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} i^4 = (\sum_{i=0}^n i)^3 + (n+1)^4$$. I've been thinking about applying $\sum_{i=0}^n i = n(n+1)/2$, but this doesn't help me much here.

Should I expand all of this using the binomial theorem ?

Comment: Wrong exponents. It is true that: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}i^\color{red}{3} = \left(\sum_{i=0}^n i\right)^\color{red}{2}.$$

Comment: Also, your LHS is a fifth-degree polynomial in $n$, while the RHS is a sixth-degree polynomial.

Comment: I can't believe I've been sitting for hours trying to prove something false ! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to prove isn't true. Counterexample: $n=2$. Then you get $$0^4 + 1^4 + 2^4 = 17 \neq (0+1+2)^3$$